# Show Tier Price in Product Grid of Sales Order creation form Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, grid, tierprice

I'm trying to show the `Tier Price` in the `Product Grid` of the sales order creation page, but can't show.

I tried the below code.

added the column to `_prepareColumns()` method from `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid.php` class

```
 $this->addColumn(
            'action', array(
            'header' => __('Price Breaks'),
            'width' => '100',
            'type' => 'action',
            'actions' => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => __('Tier Price'),
                    //'url' => array('base' => '*/*/*'),
                    'field' => 'entity_id',
                    'target'=>'_blank',
                    'id' => 'price_break',
                    'class' => 'price_break',
                   // 'onclick' => "window.open('http://www.google.com')"
                )
            ),
            'index' => 'entity_id',

        ));
```

but it's not displaying becz it's not a field.

[image]
Any help to show the tier price in the product grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did by using the below code.

Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
                $this->addColumn(
            'available_qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Price Break'),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Availableqty::class,
                'name' => 'available_qty',
                'inline_css' => 'available_qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                //'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'available_qty',
                'sortOrder' => 500
            ]
        );


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Availableqty.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class Availableqty extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Text
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface
     */
    private $stockItem;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_product;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected $sessionQuote;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $_customer;

    /**
     * Availableqty constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $_objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $_objectManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
        $this->_objectManager = $_objectManager;
        $this->_customer = $customerFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve session object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote::class);
    }


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return float|string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        //$_product = $this->_product->load($row->getId());
        $customerId = $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId();
        $customerGId = 0;
        if($customerId != null){
            $customer = $this->_customer->create()->load($customerId);
            $customerGId = $customer->getGroupId();
        }

       // $customer = $this->sessionQuote->getOrder()->getCustomer();
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($row->getId());
        $tierPriceBreak = "";
        $i = 1;
        $checkArray   = array(
            "Pack",
            "Each",
            "Case",
            "Bundle",
            "Box"
        );
        $content = "";

        if($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"){
            $tierPrice = $_product->getTierPrices();

            $stockMessage = $_product->getWebPackageBreak();
            if(count($checkArray) > 0 && $stockMessage != null){
                foreach($checkArray as $needle){
                    if(strpos( $stockMessage, $needle ) !== false ) {
                        $content = $needle;
                        $isStockMessagesExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($content == ""){
                $content = "Each";
            }

            if(count($tierPrice) > 0){
                foreach($tierPrice as $pirces){
                    if($pirces->getCustomerGroupId() == $customerGId){
                        $price = number_format($pirces->getValue(), 2, '.', '');
                        $qty = number_format($pirces->getQty(), 0, '.', '');
                        $tierPriceBreak .= " $i => Buy " . $qty." for $" . $price . "/$content ";
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            $tierPriceBreak = "";
        }


        //return $this->stockItem->getStockQty($row->getId(), $row->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        return $tierPriceBreak;
    }

}
```

It will show you a column with tier price.